# Javascript: Sort elements by fake property

Tags: javascript, properties, area

I'm trying to make a Javascript script that, after a certain amount of time, opens the link from an element in a new tab. I've got everything related to opening it done, but I can't seem to sort my element list properly.

My code is as follows:

```
function clickElement() {
    var e=document.getElementsByTagName("area");

    for (var i=0;i < e.length; i++) {
        var link=e[i].href;
        window.open(link);
    }
}
```

The code on the webpage is as follows:

```
<area href="someWebsite" "=" shape="rect" coords="0, 0, 10, 10" />
<area href="someOtherWebsite" "=" shape="rect" coords="0, 10, 10, 20" />
<area href="someThirdWebsite" shape="rect" coords="10, 0, 20, 10" />
<area href="someFourthWebsite" "=" shape="rect" coords="10, 10, 20, 20" />
```

As you can see, I am starting off by making a list of all the area elements on the page. I now want to sort those area elements, so that the first one with the "fake" property (the "=" seen in-between href="" and shape="" on some of the elements) is the one opened. The fake property changes on every page load, so there is no way for the code to know whether the first, second, third or fourth has one, other than to check it in a similar way to how I found the href property.

Do any of you guys know how to do this? Since there's no property name, just a value ("="), I can't say "e[i].=".
Keep in mind that I only have access to Javascript, and am unable to edit the HTML.

Comment: well "=" is not valid, you should add a normal attribute or class that says "SELECT ME"

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work with html you showed us ... but here is solution

```
<area href="someWebsite" "=" shape="rect" coords="0, 0, 10, 10" />
<area href="someOtherWebsite" "=" shape="rect" coords="0, 10, 10, 20" />
<area href="someThirdWebsite" shape="rect" coords="10, 0, 20, 10" />
<area href="someFourthWebsite" first="1" shape="rect" coords="10, 10, 20, 20" />
```

Here is javascript

```
function clickElement() {
    var e=document.getElementsByTagName("area");

    // First open the one with first attribute
    for (var i=0;i < e.length; i++) if( e[i].getAttribute( 'first' )) {
        var link=e[i].href;
        window.open(link);
    }

    // Then open others
    for (var i=0;i < e.length; i++) if( !e[i].getAttribute( 'first' )) {
        var link=e[i].href;
        window.open(link);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're realizing *just* how invalid your HTML is. I created a page with one of your `<area>` elements, opened it in Firefox, and used a bit of JavaScript to get the attribute names and values. They were:

```
 name          value
--------      -------------------
 href          someFourthWebsite
 "             shape=
 rect"
 coords        10, 10, 20, 20
```

Note that there's no `shape="rect"` attribute; rather, `shape` has become part of the `"` attribute, and `rect"` has become a separate attribute. (Essentially, Firefox is allowing `"` in attribute-names, without giving it any special meaning as a delimiter in that case. Obviously other browsers might handle this differently: it's very invalid, and all bets are off.)

So I suspect that your HTML is kind of useless in general, not just for this purpose.

*But*, one thing you can do is examine the `innerHTML` of the elements' `parentNode`, and find where the first `"="` is:

```
var totalHTML =
  document.getElementsByTagName('area')[0].parentNode.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
var weirdAttrIndex = totalHTML.indexOf('"="');
var i = -1;
var areaIndex = 0;
while(true)
{ areaIndex = totalHTML.indexOf('<area', areaIndex);
  if(areaIndex < 0 || areaIndex > weirdAttrIndex)
    break;
  ++i;
}
window.open(document.getElementsByTagName('area')[i].href);
```

I wouldn't expect this to be very reliable, because in the presence of HTML that is *that* invalid, who knows what can happen? But it's a start.